# bash. set -e; get result code

Tags: linux, bash

If i use -e option in bash script and code fail - i can catch it:

```
$ set -e; ( false; echo qwe; ) || echo qwe
qwe
```

But, when i try get return code i get:

```
$ (set -e; ( false; echo qwe; ) || ret=$?; echo asd  )
qwe
asd
```

Why it happens and how i can get return code?

Vesion:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, версия 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Are you trying the exit code of `false`?  Remember that `?` expands to the exit code of most recent _command_.  In the second example above, `ret` would contain exit code of `echo`.

Comment: With set -e option subprocedure "( false; echo qwe; )" must break after "false" and $ret must contain 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
 set -e; ( false; echo qwe; ) || echo qwe
```

doesn't do what you think it does:

- any subshell (`( ... )`) containing a *list* of commands (`false; echo qwe`) will execute *all* commands in that list and decide based on the *last* command's exit code whether to abort the subshell (due to `-e`); since `echo qwe`, as the subshell's last command returns `0` as its exit code (signaling *succcess*), the subshell returns `0` *overall*, and so the right side of  `||` never kicks in; try with distinct strings to echo: `set -e; ( false; echo qwe1; ) || echo qwe2`
- Trying to set a variable (`ret`, in this case) in a *subshell* for access in the originating shell is always pointless, because its scope will be confined to that subshell; to pass a value *out* from a subshell, use `stdout` output.

To achieve your goal, forget about `set -e` and instead suffix each command in the subshell with `|| exit` in order to abort right away in case of failure; the exit code on leaving the subshell will then correctly reflect the exit code of the first *failed* command, or `0`, if all commands succeeded:

```bsh
output=$( false || exit; echo qwe || exit )  # capture output from subshell
ret=$?  # $? reflects overall success of subshell
```

Comment: Oh. `set -e; ( false; echo qwe1; ) || echo qwe2` explain my mistake in question.  :) Thanks for answer!